# R mock testing with locked namespaces

Tags: r, mocking, namespaces

I'm struggling with creating some unit tests in R where I need to mock out functions like `RCurl::getURL` so they return canned output and don't required a network connection.

Here's an example:

```
library(mockthat)

test_that("API works", {

  mock_response <- mockthat::mock('[{"foo":7}]')

  mockthat::with_mock(
    getURL=mock_response,
    {
      result <- myFunction()
    })

  ...
```

This fails with the following error, **but only when I run under `devtools::check()` or `R CMD check`** (it succeeds under `devtools::test()`):

```
not ok 1 API works
  Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'getURL'
  Backtrace:
   1. mockthat::with_mock(...) test-yes.R:29:2
   2. base::lapply(mocks, set_mock)
   3. mockthat:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
   4. mockthat:::do_assign(mock$name, mock$new_value, mock$env)
   5. base::assign(name, val, envir = env)
```

Is there something I can change to get this working, or a workaround I can use?

I'm using:

```
> packageVersion('mockthat')
[1] '0.2.6'

> cat(head(capture.output(sessionInfo()), 3), sep="\n")
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.4
```

but the problem seems to also exist under `testthat`'s mocking stuff (which is now deprecated so I don't want to use it anyway) and `mockery` too.

Apologies for not creating a proper `reprex` - I'm not sure how to demonstrate the problem without having a whole package structure.

[adapted from an issue reported at https://github.com/nbenn/mockthat/issues/6]